# React AgGrid Pagination Page changed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pagination, ag-grid

I have an AgGrid, I'm simulating row grouping by rendering a table within a full width row.
Each time a row is "expanded", a full width row appears below it with it's own table contents.
Each time a row is "expanded" I also increase the amount of rows per Pagination Page (this keeps the last row's child on the same page even if the pagination page is full. (It should also be stated that only one child can be expanded at a time))

The issue I'm having is if a user changes pages (I.E. from page 1 to page 2) while there is a an expanded record on page 1, it will mess up future "expands" (since the rowsPerPage did not have an opportunity to reduce itself again)

I'm looking for a way to redraw the table when the page is changed, but if i use onPaginationChanged it triggers every time a row is expanded (Since the PagniationPageSize changes dynamically on row-expansion)

Is there a way to trigger an event each time a user directs to a new page, but not when the Pagniation Page Size changes.

Thank you and sorry in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you may use `newPage` property to check if the page has changed.

`onPaginationChanged(params)` event provides `params` object which contains `newPage` property which is set to `true` only when page is changed. If for some reason page size has changed or any other operation is performed which does not change the page number then this property is `false`

[plunkrLink](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mx5hyrw201d0zYvR)

Comment: I think this may be it! I can't however find an example of this being used; I'm still rather new to react, sorry.
The only way I can think of to accomplish this at the moment is to build my own Pagination buttons and use the button's onClick. But if possible I'd prefer to avoid this.

Comment: then lets try creating react example where we can use this. check the plunkr link in updated answer. there I have used the property to alert whenever user navigates to different page but it(alert) doesn't trigger when page size(i.e no of rows in page) is updated.

Comment: Thank you so much, your Plunker showed me how to fix my issue. I did not understand how to use that param before. Thank you again!